# import sass variable into style module

Tags: javascript, reactjs, sass, carbon-design-system

I am trying to use the carbon library for react components, and in order to import the styles for the modal, two stylesheets need to be imported, which will result in a naming collission:

this is in my `src/index.scss`
BEFORE:

```
@use "@carbon/react/scss/components/modal";
@use "@carbon/styles/scss/components/modal";

Error: Module build failed (from ./node_modules/sass-loader/dist/cjs.js):
SassError: There's already a module with namespace "modal".
  ╷
7 │ @use "@carbon/react/scss/components/modal";
  │ ━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━ original @use
8 │ @use "@carbon/styles/scss/components/modal";
  │ ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^ new @use
```

So I did some digging and the [suggestion solution](https://github.com/sass/sass/issues/2778#issuecomment-558365532) is to use an `as` operator.

AFTER:

```
@use "@carbon/react/scss/components/modal";
@use "@carbon/styles/scss/components/modal" as modal-styles;
```

how would I then import this variable (`modal-styles`) into a css module (for the modal)?

I am trying to import it in `src/components/modal/styles.module.scss`

I tried:
`@use modal-styles` -> not allowed
`@include modal-styles` -> undefined mixin error

I'm new to SASS and at a loss. thanks in advance...

Comment: Did you try `@use` "@carbon/styles/scss/components/modal" as *? then you will use `@include` (mixins/functions/variables).

Comment: could you share `styles.module.scss` ?